# running PHP websockets for over 2000 users getting *** buffer overflow detected ***: php terminated error

Tags: sockets, symfony, ubuntu, nginx, ratchet

I'm running php project with NginX and php-fpm on ubuntu server.
The site is Symfony2 based and I'm using Clank bundle for the sockets (Ratchet sockets).
I've already recompiled the php to allow open over 1024 files, but now I get an error when too much users saying buffer overflow, I guess its because of the multiple connections to a single PHP process.
My question is, what should I change in order to split the connections to multiple processes\ avoiding this crush.

Comment: ended up replacing the sockets to nodejs and socket.io based..